# Fetching active record associations in batches with include

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, padrino

Assuming standard simple models as following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

And my queries:

```
includes = {:posts => [:comments]}
person = Person.where(:id => 5).includes(includes)
```

Is there some way I can fetch comments from posts in batches? Because in some cases, a one `user` has thousands of `posts`, so the query it constructs to fetch the `comments` becomes very big and slow.

Comment: Are you lookings for [limit & offset](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#limit-and-offset)?

Comment: Seems none of the above command answers the OP's question. Question is about limiting number of records of `comments` which lies under `includes`.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this if you fetch the comments in a second query.

```
# in your controller
@person = Person.where(id: 5).includes(:posts)

# in your view (haml)
- @person.posts.each do |post|
  = post.title
  - post.comments.find_each do |comment| # find_each is batched
    = comment.message
```

Perhaps not the most clean solution (each post requires an extra query, querying in the view...), but I am not aware of a way to fetch included items in batches.